# I am confused on usecases for SpringApplicationBuilder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot for work. Up to this point I have mostly worked with JavaScript and Node. I am working through a tutorial and came across this

```
package com.example.demosubmissionform;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSubmissionFormApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    // @Override
    // protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder
    // application) {
    // return application.sources(DemoSubmissionFormApplication.class);
    // }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoSubmissionFormApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have been playing around with the code trying to figure it how it works and learn the classes used. I have look through the docs but the information I found doesn't really explain what the SpringApplicationBuilder class is doing. I have commented it out and the program still works perfectly.

Sorry for being long winded. I appreciate any assistance.

P.S : The @ComponentScan annotation is redundant right? Seeing as its already comes with the @SpringBootApplication annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code using `SpringApplicationBuilder` is required when you are packaging your Spring Boot application as a war file and deploying it to an application server or Servlet container. If you're packaging your application is a jar file and running it using `java -jar` – the typical approach when using Spring Boot – you don't need the `configure` method and you don't need to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` either.

You can learn a bit more about `SpringBootServletInitializer`, `SpringApplicationBuilder` and traditional war deployments in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

You are correct that the `@ComponentScan` annotation is redundant. As you said, it's already part of `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind elaborating on what the sources method is doing. From what I read it is used to add configuration classes and components. But in the code the only source added is the current class.

Comment: That's probably better dealt with in a separate question. The short answer is that it does register configuration classes. In this case, that configuration class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` so it enables component scanning of everything in the `com.example.demosubmissionform` package and below and auto-configuration as well.